# forest: multiple dominance without top node connection

Tags: forest

I would like to draw a tree (preferably with forest, but tikz-qtree would also be fine) where there is a multidominant structure but no top node, i.e. the top level should be two mother nodes. See picture for what kind of structure I would like to achieve. 
[image]

What I've got so far is this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[, no edge
    [D,name=D
        [A]
        [, no edge]
    ]
    [E
        [B]
        [C,name=C]
]
]
\draw (D) -- (C);
\end{forest}

\end {document}
```

So as you can see, this is quite a bit off from what I would like to have. I am still super new to (La)TeX, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for providing a MWE. You were almost there. You can remove the root node using the `phantom` key, and you need to draw your lines to and from the correct anchors of the named nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[, phantom
    [D,name=D
        [A]
        [, no edge]
    ]
    [E
        [B]
        [C,name=C]
]
]
\draw (D.south) -- (C.north);
\end{forest}

\end {document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 0):

graphviz is a great software to achieve many graphs. dot2tex can convert graphviz code into latex code.
dot2texi is a LaTeX package to include graphviz code into LaTeX documents. It must be compiled with the "-shell-escape" option.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\begin{document}
\begin{dot2tex}[dot]
graph T
{node [shape=none fixedsize=true  width=.2 height=.2]
ranksep=.5

    A [label="α" texlbl="$\alpha$"]
    B [label="β" texlbl="$\beta$"]
    C [label="α" texlbl="$\alpha$"]
    D [label="β" texlbl="$\beta$"]
    E [label="γ" texlbl="$\gamma$"]
    {rank=same A;B}
    {rank=same C;D;E}
    A --{C;E}
    C--D [style=invis]
    B -- {D;E}[constraint=false]
    }
\end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

[Graphviz code](http://ix.io/2e7N)

[LaTeX code including graphviz code](http://ix.io/2e7M)

[image]